# Single login in subdomains

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config, subdomain

I have one mvc5 application with few subdomains like this:

- example.com
- ex1.example.com
- ex2.example.com

When I log in to example.com i'm not logged in other subdomains. I added in web.config following node:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Account/Login/" protection="Validation" timeout="120" path="/" domain=".example.com"/>
</authentication>
```

But it still doesnt work :(

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are using the same [machine key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx) for for each of the applications in the subdomains.  Also you may need to set the machine key [compatibility mode to Framework20SP2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.machinekeysection.compatibilitymode.aspx).

Edit:

Take a look at this post as well: [ASP.NET Identity Cookie across subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166599/asp-net-identity-cookie-across-subdomains)

Comment: But I use One application. Every subdomain points to thge same website.

EDIT: I tried to do this for independent websites on the same hosting serwer and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Hey. Your solution worked when I had one application with few subdomains. Now I have one application for each subdomain and it doesn't work :(