# Machine key generating

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, subdomain, machinekey

I was setting up my web.config for subdomain single login. I had to set up Machine key. How can I generate machine key? RIght now i'm using key from this example:

[ASP.NET Identity Cookie across subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166599/asp-net-identity-cookie-across-subdomains)

But I suppose that if it works I have to generate somehow my own key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tool

## [Machine Key  Generator](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey)

Answer (score 0):

If you have IIS manager installed, you can generate machine keys from there by selecting your application. You can also apply them to the web.config file to save them.