# Does ASP.NET Identity 2 use machinekey to hash the password?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have created an application in ASP.NET MVC 5. Now I need to deploy the application on the server. Will my existing passwords work in ASP.NET Identity 2 when I deploy? Or do I need to use the same machine key that I have in my client machine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not need to set the machine key for passwords. The machine key is used for encryption/decryption (ViewState, Session, Cookies, etc.) not for hashing.

If you are using multiple instances of the application (think Azure Cloud Service) then you'll want to set the machine key so that cookies and auth tickets can be used across instances.

Comment: But how they hashes then?

Comment: It's fairly straightforward and you can read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957176/asp-net-identity-password-hashing

Comment: Let's say that I use one instance. When designing for Azure, I should assume that the instance is ephemeral, shouldn't I? In this case would I get an instance with a different machine key and the auth tickets will become invalid?

Comment: If you machine encrypted items to survive, you need to specify the key.