# Asp.net Identity (MVC 5) cross subdomain login and application pool identity

Tags: authentication, cross-domain, asp.net-identity-2

I used the the method introduced in [ASP.NET Identity Cookie across subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166599/asp-net-identity-cookie-across-subdomains) to implement cross sub-domain sign-in.

For example, I have two sites: account.mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com. Users who logged in the account.mydomain.com, also logged in www.mydomain.com.

However, there is a strange problem: I must change the "application pool identity" to "NetworkService" or "LocalSystem" other than default "ApplicationPoolIdentity". Or, even if someone logged in the account.mydomain.com,  he can not login www.mydomain.com.

I wonder what the reason is, and whether this is a problem that change the identity to NetworkService?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set same MachineKey in all sub domains.