# ASP.NET MVC: How do SimpleMembership, SQLSession store, Authentication, and Authorization work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I have been struggling with these elements for about 2 months.

The first problem arise when my MVC4 application was ***recycled***. The current logged-in user suddenly cannot access any controller actions which are marked **[Authorize]**. Also, any successful access to the controller action which requires database connection produces this error:

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for user
>   'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

This is weird because if I clear my authentication cookies, it works fine. So there is a problem with the **ASPXAUTH** and **.ASPNET_SessionId** cookies.

Later I figure out that those errors are caused by **session invalidation after server restart or recycle.** My session setting was in **InProc** mode. This means the session is lost every time the server is restarted or recycled.

Then I change my session config into **Custom Session SQLStore** which described in

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178588.aspx

and

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178589.aspx

The purpose is to store the **session data in SQLServer**, but the problem seems to not go away. After the server is restarted or recycled, the currently logged-in user still having the problem accessing the controller action.

My thought is that the **SimpleMembership** is not storing the login session in the database. This is how I do login:

```
WebSecurity.Login(userName, model.Password, persistCookie: true)
```

If I am correct, the system will try to match **authentication cookies** with **login session data** and determine if the authentication is still valid. This is why my user is kept having the problem because the matching between session and cookies produce some weird things.

I did a lot of research for the past 2 months, I found many similar problems with mine, but I did not find a proper solution.

The temporary solution that I am using is to logged-out the user if the server is getting recycled or restarted. This is not a good solution because if the user is in the middle of important transaction or submission, the data can be lost, and the user is redirected to login page again.

---

### Update

I have my machine key set:

```
<machineKey validationKey="685DD0E54A38F97FACF4CA27F54D3DA491AB40FE6941110A5A2BA2BC7DDE7411965D45A1E571B7B9283A0D0B382D35A0840B46EDBCE8E05DCE74DE5A37D7A5B3"
  decryptionKey="15653D093ED55032EA6EDDBFD63E4AAA479E79038C0F800561DD2CC4597FBC9E"
  validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

I try to debug my custom SQL session store, I found out that there is no authentication session is stored in the database. I can only find `"__ControllerTempData"` retrieved from my SQL session, and nothing else.

Please correct me if I am wrong, the way the website reuse the authentication cookies and validates it is by comparing authentication cookie and the authentication session, am I right?

Apparently, SimpleMembership Login() does not store the authentication session into the SQL state server.

Then which session key is used for the comparing?

Comment: I really hope that isn't your real machineKey. If it is, change it now.

Comment: None of the "built in" membership providers store anything in session. The user name is stored in the authtoken (the authentication cookie), and then the principal and identity objects are recreated during each new request. Are you manually storing anything in session that you use for security?

Comment: You can also see exactly what the provider is doing by viewing the source: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs and https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/WebSecurity.cs#L259

Comment: @TiesonT. links you provided are no longer working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so silly for me. I did not put:

```
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);
```

in my application intialization (global.asax or any initialization code called from global.asax).

I only call `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` when the code need it and somehow the web misses `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` when I made request while the server restarted.

There is no connection between session and auth cookie which perform some validation. There is no validation between them. The login auth is purely hold by cookies.

I still need custom sql store session tho. Because `TempData` becomes persistence. This will not causing form submission to fail while the server is restarted.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've added a [machineKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx) setting to your web.config, otherwise your site uses an auto-generated machine key. **If the machine key changes, anything encrypted with the previous key can't be decrypted**, which will cause (in part) the error you're seeing.

I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30689273/534109) to a different question that covers adding a machineKey to your web.config, and how to generate the keys yourself, or you can use code from [this app I made](https://github.com/tiesont/machinekey-generator).

The gist is thus:

1) Add a machine key, like so (filling in the appropriate values)"

```
<machinekey compatibilitymode="Framework45"
            validation="HMACSHA256"
            validationkey="YOURVALIDATIONKEYHERE"
            decryption="AES"
            decryptionkey="YOURDECRYPTIONKEYHERE" />
```

2) Restart the app pool. You'll have one more round of users potentially having issues accessing the site (unless you also change the cookie name), but clearing their cookies will solve that problem.

Comment: I already have my machine key set. This is not solving the problem.