# Session sharing among the sub domains not woprking in asp.net mvc5 on azure cloud

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I am working on an asp.net mvc 5 project which is a sub domain based multi tenant saas application like t1.abc.com for tenant1 and t2.abc.com for tenant2.

I am trying to share the session across the sub domains for supper admins and I configured web config with root domain as

```
 <httpCookies domain=".abc.com"/>
```

But it is not working, even after I login to abc.com when I go to t1.abc.com in the next tab still it prompts login page.

The session store is configured to point to the RedisSessionStateStore and the application is deployed in the azure cloud web apps.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out. I used owin middle ware so the solution is here in this link [ASP.NET Identity Cookie across subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166599/asp-net-identity-cookie-across-subdomains)